# Когда может пригодится пространство имен System.Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, .net, кодогенераторы

Когда может пригодится пространство имен System.Reflection.Emit ?

Вроде, в .NET предусмотрены классы, которые позволяют генерировать динамически сборки на высокоуровневом языке.

Зачем погружаться в низкий уровень?

Comment: _Вроде, в .NET предусмотрены классы, которые позволяют генерировать динамически сборки на высокоуровневом языке._ - какие например?

Comment: @Grundy,CodeDomProvider

Comment: [_The CSharpCodeProvider is a Microsoft extension to the CLI so it may not be supported in, say, Mono.

As far as the differences between the two, however, Reflection.Emit should be available on all platforms. Another difference is that you can use Reflection.Emit without generating source files to compile using a CodeDomProvider. They are both ways of generating assemblies at runtime, it's really more of a question about which suits your needs._](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/812629/Re-System-Reflection-Emit-vs-System-CodeDom-Compil.aspx)

Comment: @Grundy: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, потому что мне кажется слишком мало :-) А сам я не особо вникал :) Ну и возможно вопрос несколько шире и хотелось увидеть сравнение не только этих двух подходов но и еще каких-то

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Reflection.Emit` — это для тех, кто хочет создавать динамические сборки (а не добавлять что-то в существующие) на чистом IL (хардкор короче). Подробнее ниже.

### А может вам надо что-то другое и желательно попроще?

- Если вам просто нужен динамический тип, может вам просто подойдёт `dynamic` или `ExpandoObject`? И никакой генерации кода, правда о проверке на этапе компиляции можно забыть.
- Вам нужен метод (может также их группа), который будет принимать и анализировать лямбда выражения? Тогда используйте Expression Trees. Для простых случаев будет хорошо, но если вы надумали написать свой ORM, то это занятие совсем не из простых. При этом помните, что для Expression Trees поддерживаются только однострочные лямбда-выражения.
- Если вам нужен динамически генерируемый HTML (вдруг), а это не веб-приложение, то используйте [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine). Также симулируя веб-приложение, можно добавить поддержку Intellisense.

---

### Генерация кода

Если вкратце: если вам нужна всё же полноценная генерация кода, то используйте Roslyn. Потому что мощный и платформенно независимый. Возможно также будет полезен T4 (особенно если нужен не-C# и не-VB код).

### Преимущества и недостатки `Reflection.Emit`

Преимущества

- создание динамической сборки на чистом IL: вы полностью контролируете код и можете писать высоко оптимизированный код. Преимущество тут ещё в том, что если есть какая-то возможность недоступная в C#, но доступная в CLR, вы тоже сможете её задействовать.
- хорошая производительность генерации кода. Созданный вами код сразу компилируется в сборку (в отличие от `Microsoft.CodeDom`, но c Roslyn всё хорошо, ибо он дёргает компилятор как сервис).
- платформенно-независимый подход (в отличие от `Microsoft.CodeDom`, который специфичен только для реализации Microsoft, но Roslyn тоже платформенно независим)

Недостатки

- приходится прописывать простейшие вещи вроде циклов (просто серия переходов). Вам приходится думать на низком уровне. Поэтому сложно создавать нетривиальные программы.
- вы обязаны генерировать новую сборку. Если вам это подходит, то это не недостаток. Но если вы хотите что-то добавить в существующую, то это невозможно средствами `Reflection.Emit`.

Исходя из этого решайте применять вам `Reflection.Emit` или нет. Но я полагаю, что это совсем хардкор.

### Альтернативы

- `Microsoft.CodeDom`
- Roslyn
- T4

### `Microsoft.CodeDom` vs `Reflection.Emit`

## Способы программирования

Сгенерированный код с помощью `Microsoft.CodeDom` может быть частью решения (классы LINQ to SQL, WSDL, XSD сгенерированы таким способом). Вы также можете использовать `partial` классы для настойки сгенерированного кода. Когда используете `Reflection.Emit` вы обязаны создавать новую сборку.

Когда вы используете `Reflecion.Emit` вы программируете с помощью IL-команд. Когда вы программируете c помощью `Microsoft.CodeDom` вы создаёте команды C#.

Поэтому код `Microsoft.CodeDom` будет проще создавать, так вы программируете более высокоуровневыми командами. Код созданный на `Reflecion.Emit` будет сложней создать на IL (к примеру циклы надо будет создавать с помощью переходов), особенно когда вы программируете сложную логику.

Из этого следует, что возможностей на `Reflection.Emit` больше (так у IL больше возможностей, чем у C#). Однако для каждой привычной вещи на C# придётся писать намного больше кода.

## Производительность

Код `Microsoft.CodeDom` будет медленней, чем `Reflection.Emit`, так как он компилируется, затем генерируется C#-код, затем этот сгенерированный код компилируеся. `Reflection.Emit` сразу компилируется в сборку.

## Платформенная (не)зависимость

Как верно заметил @Grundy это платформенная независимость для `Reflecion.Emit`. А `Microsoft.CodeDom` доступен только на платформах от Microsoft.

### Roslyn (основано на [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852926/microsoft-roslyn-vs-codedom))

Однако я бы не использовал `Microsoft.CodeDom`. Ибо Roslyn мощней и выразительней.

- Roslyn есть на Mono (платформенно-независимый).
- Roslyn в отличии от `Microsoft.CodeDom` не просто является обёрткой на csc.exe, а может также анализировать код семантически, динамически компилировать и разбирать код. Это способ создавать любой инстумент для C# и VB. Поэтому есть возможности от форматирования код до нахождения всех ссылок в решении для данного символа.

## T4

А что если вам не надо динамически генерируемую сборку, а нужно дополнить часть существующего решения?

Или если надо динамически сгенерированные файлы, но не C# или VB? К примеру, скажем JavaScript или CSS. (Для HTML рекомендую RazorEngine если что, но с помощью T4 тоже можно). Или вообще какого-то экзотического расширения. И ещё, усугубив задачу, этих файлов надо несколько, но количество известно только в момент исполнения кода.

Тогда вы можете использовать T4. 
Это инструмент в Visual Studio (или [просто консольная утилита](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx)), который используется для генерации кода любого языка. Также доступен и в MonoDevelop.

Сразу скажу, что Entity Framework (не .NET Core) использует T4.

Концептуально похоже на ASPX, только код между C#-вставками `<#` `#>` не обязательно HTML/CSS/JavaScript, а на языке программирования целевого файла. [Мануалы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

Из минусов

- Нет встроенной поддержки подсветки синтаксиса и Intellisense в Visual Studio, поэтому приходится либо привыкать, либо устанавливать третьесторонние плагины для Visual Studio.

Comment: [Generating Files with the TextTransform Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx)

Comment: @Grundy добавил мануал, правда ссылку, ближе к корню.

Comment: В моей ссылке речь про отдельную утилиту, которую можно запустить и получить по шаблону результат. То есть это не _только в Visual Studio_

Comment: Я бы вынес Expression Trees в самое начало, потому что они, во-первых, перекрывают большую часть потребностей в динамической кодогенерации - а во-вторых, позволяют удобно эту самую кодогенерацию декомпозировать.

Comment: @Grundy ну это совсем хардкор cоздавать проекты не в Visual Studio.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, там просто основной вопрос про Reflection.Emit

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а кто говорил про проекты? это раз. Шаблоны с `.tt` можно хоть в текстовом редакторе писать - это два. Кроме студии есть еще например MonoDevelop какой-нибудь - это три

Comment: @PavelMayorov я вынес.

Comment: @Grundy 1. Вы правы про MonoDevelop, поэтому удалил пункт про зависимость от Visual Studio. 2. Добавил краткий ответ в начало про `Reflection.Emit` так как вопрос про него.

Answer (score 18):

Как уже сказано в предыдущем ответе, существует несколько способов кодогенерации. Часть из них позволяют генерировать код в дизайн-тайме, т.е. в IDE (T4). Другая - генерировать C# код во время исполнения (CodeDom), а третья - генерировать исполняемый код (т.е. IL) во время исполнения (Reflection.Emit).

И хотя может показаться, что последний случай довольно редкий, но это не так. Даже не задумываясь, вы этим делом пользуетесь постоянно.

## Компилируемые регулярные выражения

Да, если вы создаете регулярное выражение следующим образом: `var regex = new Regex("abc", RegexOptions.Compiled);`, то среда исполнения сгенерирует класс со специализированным конечным автоматом с помощью Reflection.Emit, а не будет интерпретировать регулярное выражение каждый раз.

## Сериализаторы

Да, большинство сериализаторов используют отражение, но это весьма медленная штука. Поэтому тот же XmlSerializer сгенерирует специальный класс сериализатора во время исполнения и сохранит его в специальной папке для последующего использования. Этот же подход используется и бинарным сериализатором, да и любимый всеми Newtonsoft.Json не брезгует кодогенерацией.

## PostSharp и прочие AOP

Например, мы хотим сделать ран-тайм декоратор для логгирования. Если у нас есть виртуальный метод, помеченный атрибутом `[LogMethod]`, то мы можем сгенерировать класс наследника, который переопределит этот виртуальный метод и будет логировать все аргументы метода, а уже потом вызывать базову реализацию.

Постшарп и другие AOP фреймворки построены непосредственно на технологии генерации кода во время исполнения.

## Деревья выражений

Да, Expression Trees в C# - это высокоуровневая конструкция, но метод `Expression.Compile` на самом деле использует Reflection.Emit для генерации кода во время исполнения.

## Object-to-object mappers

Всякие Automapper-ы используют Reflection.Emit для генерации соответствия между отображением экземпляров одного типа в другой.

## ORM

Это частный случай мапперов и в них используется кодогенерация по полной программе. NHibernate, LINQ 2 SQL, Entity Fraework, все они генерируют классы во время исполнения для маппинга объектов друг на друга или для перехвата вызовов метода репозиториев.

## Mock frameworks

Rhyno Mocks, Moq и другие, все они основаны либо на Expression Trees либо напрямую на Reflection.Emit-е (да, многие mock framework-и используют DynamicProxy, который уже использует Reflection.Emit) для генерации заглушек при тестировании.

## WCF и прочие коммуникационные штуки

Да, и в них тоже генерируются различные прокси классы для инспекции вызовов и другой инструментации во время исполнения.

## Application Insights и прочие логгеры/анализаторы

И снова, для того, чтобы сделать процесс логгирования наиболее простым, в подобных инструментах используется кодогенерация.

## DLR - Dynamic Languagage Runtime

В CLR есть специальная функциональность для взаимодействия с динамически типизированными языками, типа Python, Ruby etc. Там на полную катушку используется DLR для повышения производительности.

Вы не поверите, но вы можете использовать Reflection.Emit (хоть и косвенно) даже для обхода стандартных проблем языка C#.

Возможно вы знаете, что `new T()` ограничение для дженериков - это страх и ужас. Там используется отражение, что серьезно сказывается на производительности, да еще и заворачивает исключения, возникшие при создании экземпляра, в `TargetInvocationException`. Я уже в нескольких проектах сталкивался, что этот метод существенно портит end-to-end время исполнения. Поэтому в этих проектах используется специализированный `CustomActivactor`:

```
public static class CustomActivator
{
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return ActivatorImpl<T>.Factory();
    }

    private class ActivatorImpl<T> where T : new()
    {
        // Под колпаком используем Reflection.Emit!
        private static readonly 
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> _expr = () => new T();
        public static readonly Func<T> Factory = _expr.Compile();
    }
}
```

Теперь наш активатор не страдает от проблем с производительностью и не оборачивает исключения из конструкторов в занудный `TargetInvocationExpression`.

З.Ы. На самом деле, я коснулся лишь части сценариев, тот же ASP.NET использует кодогенерацию по полной. Чтобы понять всю полноту картины можно попробовать поискать самому. Например, можно поискать тип [ILGenerator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/ilgenerator.cs,cfc4df22600be8e8) или что-то еще из пространства имен System.Reflection.Emit:

- На [гитхаб](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=ILGenerator&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93): найдено 40К ссылок на `ILGenerator` (там нет семантического поиска, поэтому многие ссылки будут не валидными, но дадут понять масштаб трагедии).
- [в сорцах МС-а](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/ilgenerator.cs,cfc4df22600be8e8,references): десятки ссылок и примеров использования, большую часть которых я привел ранее.

UPDATE: данная тема вылилась в довольно длинный пост, посвященный тонкостям работы активатора, обобщений и кодогенерации - [Dissecting the new() constraint in C#: a perfect example of a leaky abstraction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/02/01/dissecting-the-new-constraint-in-c-a-perfect-example-of-a-leaky-abstraction/).

Comment: а почему CustomActivator не страдает от проблем с производительностью? если добавить эти же статические поля в генерик класс - поправят ли они проблему с производительностью?

Comment: Потому что там генериуется IL для создания экземпляра и этот IL кэшируется. Поэтому там не дергается отражение каждый раз.

Comment: то есть если добавить просто статическое поле, в котором сразу вызвать `expression.Compie()` - то внутренний класс можно опустить?

Comment: Кстати. а почему в таком случае просто не собрать в expression вызов конструктора? тогда и `new()` ограничение не нужно ведь?

Comment: По первому: внутренний класс нужен, чтобы не делать внешний класс обобщенным. И new() нужно, поскольку компилятор даст по рукам на конструкцию `new T()` если на `T` не наложено это ограничение.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, а разве классы для маппинга не генерятся на высокоуровневом языке?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Нет. Там же просто нет информации в дизайн тайме. Вот пример: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/Mapping/Accessors.cs,35

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, так, а что мешает на высокоуровневом языке генерить сборку? Проблемы с переносимостью?

Comment: _И new() нужно, поскольку компилятор даст по рукам на конструкцию new T() если на T не наложено это ограничение._ - я имел ввиду `new()` не нужно, если собирать вызов конструктора через ExpressionTree

Comment: Если собирать совсем вручную, то да. Но ведь тогда мы переложим проблему с времени компиляции на время исполнения. Разве так лучше?

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, проблему чего? проверки что у типа есть нужный конструктор? да. Но при этом - обойдем ограничение на то что только конструктор по умолчанию, и, возможно, будет отсутствовать проблема с производительностью после компиляции Expression

Comment: @Grundy но ведь это серьезная проблема: теперь можно будет "попытаться" инстанцировать любой тип и получить ошибку "дефолтный конструктор не найден" в рантайме. Это важно. А проблемы с производительностью в случае Expression и так нет. Так что мы проблему добавим, но ни одну проблему не решим.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, решим проблему только дефолтного конструктора, ведь собрать вызов можно любого

Comment: Мы ушли куда-то в сторону: если цель - вызывать любой конструктор, то проверить это можно только в рантайме. У меня же пример, как обойти одну конкретную проблему и остаться в рамках фичи языка C#, но без негативных ее сторон. Так что я не пойму, что мы тут обсуждаем уже:(((

Comment: @Grundy Если интересно, готов перейти в чат и обсудить там этот вопрос.

Comment: Лучше вот в этот: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--

Answer (score 2):

Существующие ответы несколько устарели. В дополнение к ним следует отметить, что в .NET Core и .NET 5+ возможности System.Reflection.Emit (SRE) ограничены по сравнению с .NET Framework/Mono: генерировать динамические сборки в памяти можно, но [сохранить их в исполняемый файл нельзя](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15704). Это значит, что если кто-то хотел бы использовать SRE как основу для кодогенерации в своем компиляторе, эту идею придется отбросить в условиях современного .NET. Использованию SRE для генерации сериализаторов/мапперов это не мешает, разве что теперь динамическую сборку нельзя кэшировать между разными запусками программы - ее нужно всегда генерировать заново, даже для одного и того же типа. Если нужно сохранять динамическую сборку в файл, в качестве альтернативы можно использовать [Mono.Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) или [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/).

Кроме того, в C# недавно появился новый функционал для динамической генерации кода, [Source generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/). В некоторых случаях, когда обычно использовался SRE/CodeDom/T4, теперь можно попробовать его.