# Способы создания объектов в C#

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Я знаю 1 способ создать объекта в C#:

```
public static class ObjectCreator
{
    public static T GetObject<T>() where T : class
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Есть ли более производительные?

**Update класс с известными способами:**

```
 public class ObjectCreator<T> where T: new()
{
    protected Func<T> V4Lambda;

    protected Func<T> V5Lambda;

    public ObjectCreator()
    {
        Type sType = typeof(T);

        //V4
        V4Lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.New(sType)).Compile();

        //V5
        V5Lambda = DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler.GenerateFactory<T>();
    }

    public T V1()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }

    public T V2()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public T V3()
    {
        return CustomActivator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public T V4()
    {
        return V4Lambda();
    }

    public T V5()
    {
        return V5Lambda();
    }
}

public static class CustomActivator
{
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return ActivatorImpl<T>.Factory();
    }

    private class ActivatorImpl<T> where T : new()
    {
        private static readonly Expression<Func<T>> _expr = () => new T();

        public static readonly Func<T> Factory = _expr.Compile();
    }
}

public static class DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler
{
    public static Func<T> GenerateFactory<T>() where T : new()
    {
        Expression<Func<T>> expr = () => new T();
        NewExpression newExpr = (NewExpression)expr.Body;

        var method = new DynamicMethod(
            name: "lambda",
            returnType: newExpr.Type,
            parameterTypes: new Type[0],
            m: typeof(DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler).Module,
            skipVisibility: true);

        ILGenerator ilGen = method.GetILGenerator();
        // Constructor for value types could be null
        if (newExpr.Constructor != null)
        {
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, newExpr.Constructor);
        }
        else
        {
            LocalBuilder temp = ilGen.DeclareLocal(newExpr.Type);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, temp);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, newExpr.Type);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, temp);
        }

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>));
    }
}
```

Результаты моего тестирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: самый производительный - использование конструктора

Comment: @Grundy к сожалению он мне не подходит

Comment: используйте ограничение [new()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) для обобщенного метода и вызывайте конструктор `new T()`

Comment: [CustomActivactor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608238/186999)

Comment: @rdorn, в случае new будет вызван тот же самый `System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>`

Comment: можно дописать кусок il с вызовом конструктора

Comment: @Grundy приведите пожалуйста пример как это сделать

Comment: @Grundy, _"в случае new будет вызван тот же самый..."_ ого, ничего себе, всегда полагал, что `new T()` - _true_-оператор.

Comment: @i-one, да, я тоже не так давно об этом узнал :)

Comment: В v4 можно убрать `Expression.Convert`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В следующих статьях Сергея Теплякова

- [Исследуем new() ограничение в C#](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2017/02/dissecting-new-constraint-in-c.html)
- [Dissecting the new() constraint in C#: a perfect example of a leaky abstraction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/02/01/dissecting-the-new-constraint-in-c-a-perfect-example-of-a-leaky-abstraction/)

делается вывод, что самый быстрый способ создания объекта - это распарсить лямбду в выражение и скомпилировать его:

```
public static class DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler
{
    public static Func<T> GenerateFactory<T>() where T:new()
    {
        Expression<Func<T>> expr = () => new T();
        NewExpression newExpr = (NewExpression)expr.Body;

        var method = new DynamicMethod(
            name: "lambda", 
            returnType: newExpr.Type,
            parameterTypes: new Type[0],
            m: typeof(DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler).Module,
            skipVisibility: true);

        ILGenerator ilGen = method.GetILGenerator();
        // Constructor for value types could be null
        if (newExpr.Constructor != null)
        {
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, newExpr.Constructor);
        }
        else
        {
            LocalBuilder temp = ilGen.DeclareLocal(newExpr.Type);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, temp);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, newExpr.Type);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, temp);
        }

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>));
    }
}
```

```
public static class FastActivator<T> where T : new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extremely fast generic factory method that returns an instance
    /// of the type <typeparam name="T"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Func<T> Create =
        DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler.GenerateFactory<T>();
}
```

```
                  Method |       Mean |    StdDev |  Gen 0 |
------------------------ |----------- |---------- |------- |
 ActivatorCreateInstance | 95.0161 ns | 1.0861 ns | 0.0005 |
        FuncBasedFactory |  6.5741 ns | 0.0608 ns | 0.0034 |
  FastActivator_T_Create |  5.1715 ns | 0.0466 ns | 0.0034 |
```

Comment: там автор вопроса писал, что у него в принципе нет Expression :) поэтому часть с его разбором можно было выкинуть :-)

Comment: Во-первых, где? Во-вторых, а как его может не быть? Тут и про position говорили, что нет, в соседнем вопросе...

Comment: @Grundy это в одном проекте нету, в других есть. Ответ хороший. Правда использовать этот вариант в своем текущем проекте я не могу :(

Comment: [_Кастомный активатор, работает быстрее примерно на 40% на моей машине, но использует `Expressions`, значит нельзя использовать для .net compact (а мне бы хотелось):_](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/715920/2)

Comment: @mirypoko, _Правда использовать этот вариант в своем текущем проекте я не могу_ - почему?

Comment: @Grundy в .net compact нету `Expression`, а мне нужно писать программу, которая постоянно взаимодействует с бд для Windows CE 5

Comment: @mirypoko, ну так и убери из кода все, что связано с Expression. по сути там поменяется только то как создается метод, например можно так: `var d = new DynamicMethod("creator", typeof(T), null, true);`, и то, откуда конструктор берется. например так: `var constr = typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);` все остальное точно такое же

Comment: @mirypoko, по ссылке и другие реализации есть. Можешь из них выбрать.

Comment: @Grundy, _`typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)`_ - это вроде неуниверсально? Что если есть конструктор с параметрами, имеющими дефаултные значения?

Comment: @Qwertiy, для этого случая и стоит ограничение `new()`, если у класса нет конструктора по умолчанию, то будет ошибка компиляции и до кода получения конструктора дело даже не дойдет

Comment: @Grundy, хм.. да: https://ideone.com/mIHCGz. Я почему-то думал, что это скомпилируется.

Answer (score 6):

Вы не должны заниматься низкоуровневыми микрооптимизациями практически никогда. (Потому что компилятор рано или поздно сумеет оптимизировать лучше.)

Но если в каком-то месте вам **реально нужна** оптимизация, то достаточно просто передать создающую функцию `Func<T>` куда нужно, и всё:

```
public class ObjectCreator<Т>
{
    Func<T> create;
    public ObjectCreator(Func<T> create) => this.create = create;
    public T GetObject() => create();
}
```

Вы потеряете немного абстракцию, но вам же ехать, а не шашечки? Это самый быстрый путь.

Ещё быстрее будет просто в нужном месте вызвать нужный конструктор. Потому что вызов делегата небесплатен. С другой стороны, если вам нужны нанооптимизации, вы выбрали себе не ту платформу.

Бенчмарки:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.9, OS=Windows 7 SP1 (6.1.7601)
Processor=Intel Core i7-2600K CPU 3.40GHz (Sandy Bridge), ProcessorCount=8
Frequency=3320429 Hz, Resolution=301.1659 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2053.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2053.0


                                         Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
----------------------------------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
                    V1_Activator_CreateInstance | 70.639 ns | 0.3354 ns | 0.3138 ns |
                        V2_NewGenericConstraint | 77.813 ns | 0.2788 ns | 0.2608 ns |
              V3_CustomActivator_CreateInstance | 20.237 ns | 0.0562 ns | 0.0498 ns |
                          V4_Expression_Compile | 11.175 ns | 0.1693 ns | 0.1584 ns |
 V5_DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler_GenerateFactory |  4.822 ns | 0.0322 ns | 0.0301 ns |
                                V6_Factory_Func |  3.967 ns | 0.0247 ns | 0.0231 ns |
                     V7_Direct_Constructor_Call |  3.047 ns | 0.0207 ns | 0.0194 ns |
```

Comment: Свои замеры? У @SergeyTeplyakov результаты другие...

Comment: @Qwertiy, может зависеть от машины на которой запускались тесты

Comment: @Qwertiy: Свои, только что замерял. У меня .NET 4.7, последний, а у него в статье?

Comment: @VladD, непонятно только почему `V4_Expression_Compile`  так сильно отличается от `V5_DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler_GenerateFactory` если там по сути - тот же самый код

Comment: @Grundy: Моя не знать. Какой там код нагенерируется, не понятно. А ещё, может быть, динамические модули по другому обрабатывает jitter?

Comment: Не смог у него версию найти, но статья 1 февраля написана, так что у тебя новее.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну и компилятор часто обновляется, так что цены этим бенчмаркам реально не так уж много.

Comment: @VladD, да всё равно примерно так же - функция и динамически скомпилированый метод - самые быстрые. Только у тебя они местами поменялись.

Comment: @VladD, суть в том, что код ил для V5_DynamicModuleLambdaCompiler_GenerateFactory как раз скопирован с исходников для newexpression

Comment: @Grundy: Ну то есть можно задать вопрос, почему такая разница в скорости. И покопаться в сгенерированном IL. Но я на него не отвечу, я завтра уезжаю в отпуск :)

Comment: @VladD, но ты уезжаешь завтра ;-)

Comment: @VladD, какой отпуск может быть??? ты же только что в нем был???

Comment: @Grundy: Не, это было весной :)

Comment: Коллеги, по поводу того, почему динамически сгенерированные функции могут быть медленнее: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13431573/276994