# Посоветуйте способ создания классов в зависимости от типа класса данных

Tags: c#

Извиняюсь за такой заголовок, но не мог придумать ничего более понятно описывающего мою проблему (если можно её так назвать).

У меня есть классы моделей, которые наследуются от базового класса Module (хранит общие для всех поля, одно из них - int Id).

Моделей много и вот некоторые из них:

- CameraPosition
- CameraMovement
- CharacterPosition
- CharacterMovement
  и т.д.

кроме филдов в них ничего нет:

```
    public class CameraPosition : Module
    {
        public Vector3 Position;
        public float Zoom;
    }
```

Также для каждого класса модели есть класс действия.

```
public class CameraPositionAction : ActionBase
{
    ...
    private readonly CameraPosition _cameraPosition;

    public override string Id { get; }

    public CameraPositionAction(CameraPosition cameraPosition)
    {
        _cameraPosition = cameraPosition;
    }

    public override void Do(Action<ActionBase> complete)
    {
        base.Do(complete);

        ...
    }
}
```

Теперь представим, что есть список модулей загруженных из файла:

```
List<Module> Modules = LoadAllModules();
```

И мне нужно создать такой же список действий по этим данным. Сейчас я использую фабрику в которую передаю модуль и в зависимости от типа модуля получаю действие.

```
public class ActionFactory : IActionFactory
{
    public IAction Create(Module module)
    {
        switch (module)
        {
            case CameraPositionModule cameraPositionModule:
                return new CameraPositionAction(cameraPositionModule);
            case CameraMovementModule cameraMovementModule:
                return new CameraMovementAction(cameraMovementModule);
            default:
                Debug.LogError($"Action for {module.GetType().Name} not found.");
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Мне не очень нравится этот способ получения действий т.к. при каждом добавлении новых модулей нужно не забывать добавлять в фабрику новый тип в switch.
Есть ли способ лучше? может при помощи атрибутов или чего-то ещё? или делаю из мухи слона?

Comment: А нельзя просто модулям дать метод `GetAction`?

Comment: Мне кажется, из мухи слона. Если для каждой модели (модуля?) можно сделать действие, сделайте его абстрактным методом в `Module`. Или хотя бы геттер, который это действие возвращает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, не хотелось ложить какую-то логику в модели, но ничего страшного в данном случае не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы указал, что все классы реализуют интерфейс IModule, вынес бы ваш метод Do в интерфейс и создавал бы классы при помощи рефлексии.

Как-то так:

```
void Main()
{
    var loader = new Loader();
    loader.GetAllModules();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public interface IModule
{
    void Do();
}

public class ModuleA : BaseModule, IModule
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().ToString());
        CwWhoIAm(this.GetType());
    }
}

public class ModuleB : BaseModule, IModule
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().ToString());
        CwWhoIAm(this.GetType());
    }
}

public class BaseModule
{
    protected void CwWhoIAm(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I Am: {t}");
    }
}

public class Loader
{
    public Loader()
    {
        EnshureCache();
    }

    public void GetAllModules()
    {
        foreach (var type in Cache)
        {
            var task = (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            task.Do();
        }
    }

    private static void EnshureCache()
    {
        if (Cache == null)
        {
            Cache = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Where(t => typeof(IModule).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass)
                            .ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static Type[] Cache;
}
```

Причем, я не создавал бы отдельный Action к классу, содержащему данные - а последуя заветам ООП инкапсулировал бы логику обработки в сам класс. (Это же предлагает и yolosora)

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня обычно не бывает разнообразия конструкторов, поэтому инстанцирование везде одинаково. Помогает мне избежать этого разнообразия Mediatr, который я передаю как зависимость на конструктор, тем и обхожусь, что-то типа:

```
var task = (ISomething)Activator.CreateInstance(type, this.Mediator, cancellationToken);
```

Также можно и в базовый абстрактный класс вынести метод, я этим подходом пользуюсь реже, поэтому сходу под рукой примера нет.

Вообще, Activator.CreateInstance - очень мощная штука, рекомендую.

См. поиском по so [Activator.CreateInstance](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+Activator.CreateInstance), особенно [Способы создания объектов в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715920/213987)

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ и ссылки, буду разбираться.

Comment: Эээ, зачем рефлексия? Почему не фабрики?