# LINQ Expressions и Рефлексия

Tags: c#, .net

Наткнулся на очень интересный [код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538377/4244707):

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class FieldAccessor
{
    private static readonly ParameterExpression fieldParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    private static readonly ParameterExpression ownerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

    public FieldAccessor(Type type, string fieldName)
    {
        var field = type.GetField(fieldName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (field == null) throw new ArgumentException();

        var fieldExpression = Expression.Field(
            Expression.Convert(ownerParameter, type), field);

        Get = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
            Expression.Convert(fieldExpression, typeof(object)),
            ownerParameter).Compile();

        Set = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(
            Expression.Assign(fieldExpression,
                Expression.Convert(fieldParameter, field.FieldType)), 
            ownerParameter, fieldParameter).Compile();
    }

    public Func<object, object> Get { get; }

    public Action<object, object> Set { get; }
}
```

Автор утверждает, что он производительный стандартной рефлекссии и даже ответ отмечен, как принятый.

Однако, не понимаю, чем он лучше стандартного кеширования поля. Или это плацебо?

Comment: Если есть сомнения насчёт производительности - возьмите и померяйте. Но да, этот код быстрее рефлексии, т.к. он собирает с помощью linq обычный метод для доступа к полю, а не дёргает рефлексию кждый раз.

Comment: По сути это кодогенерация, см.: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608238/218063 поэтому она быстрее рефлексии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь кэшируется не само поле, а метод доступа к нему. Подразумевается, что для каждого поля класса, которое требуется динамически устанавливать или читать, создаётся свой экземпляр класса `FieldAccessor`. После этого созданный объект используется многократно. Если то же самое делать по старинке, выглядеть это будет так:

```
FieldInfo pi = type.GetField(fieldName, /* те же самые флаги */);
return pi.GetValue(object);
```

Этот вызов будет медленнее, чем динамически сгенерированный аксессор специально для указанного поля, т.к. через лямбда-выражение мы генерируем код, содержащий только обращение к полю так, как будто бы мы написали просто `return fieldName`. Правда, он будет упакован в делегат, что всё равно даст некоторый overhead по сравнению с обычным полем. В принципе, в .NET 1 или 2, где ещё не было интерпретируемых запросов, такое тоже можно было сделать посредством генерации MSIL на `Reflection.Emit`, но это гораздо сложнее. Возможность описания лямбда-выражения как структуры данных с последующей компиляцией делает то же самое гораздо проще.

Надо помнить, что получение поля по имени и тем более компиляция лямбда-выражения в MSIL - это операции не моментальные, поэтому выигрыш в производительности от использования такого класса мы получим только в том случае, когда мы создали один объект для каждого поля, а потом многократно его используем.

Comment: В примере создается аксессор для Public'а=> я готов поверить, что в "как будто бы мы написали просто return fieldName". Однако, если речь идет о приватном поле? Каким образом Expression до него доберется? Или это не будет работать с приватным поле?

Comment: Эффективно вернуть Private может только сам класс владеющий этим полем, ИМХО. Если конечно внутри Expression не происходит вообще откровенная магия.

Comment: Или если IL код может начехать на инкапсуляцию...

Comment: IL код может начихать на инкапсуляцию, верно. Небольшой overhead от использования делегата - как раз плата за это. Я в своё время пользовался библиотекой DynamicMethodFactory для этого, которая была сделана через Reflection.Emit

Comment: Хм... Ну если рассматривать с такого ракурса, то тогда все понятно. Я думал с точки зрения инкапсуляции и не понимал, почему это быстрее. Получается, что всякие модификаторы доступа- это для языков высокого уровня, а в IL мы можем творить, что душе угодно?

Comment: Ну, не всё, MSIL тоже верифицируется, чем больше подобных трюков используется в коде, тем меньше у него будет привилегий. Например, вряд ли Вы сможете написать хранимую процедуру на С# с подобными махинациями.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под привелегиями? Например, я взял откомпилированные C# исходники и получил IL код. Модифицировал какой-то класс, что он теперь может обращаться куда не должен. Потом скопилировал DLL и подгрузил в C#. Это же по идее будет прозрачно для конечного языка, как я понимаю. Если C# конечно не верифицирует сборку, что там можно делать в конкретном языке.

Comment: Если шарите в этом вопросе, то можете сюда заглянуть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907255/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-il-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F-net