# Что возможно в IL чего нельзя сделать на языке высокого уровня .NET?

Tags: .net

В общем, задался этим вопрос из-за этого [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907159/32793) по другому вопросу.

В нем утверждается, что в `IL` коде можно получать доступ к приватным полям другого класса забивая на инкапсуляцию, естественным путем не прибегая к дорогостоящей рефлексии.

(Так ли это?)

Получается, что я могу взять `IL`-код, полученный после компиляции на `C#` и добавить в него какое-нибудь экзотическое поведение(Которое не запрещено в `IL`), которого нельзя добиться языком высокого уровня, скомпилировать и подключить эту сборку к проекту и прозрачно использовать на каком-нибудь `C#` ?

Собственно, интересует вопрос, на сколько все дозволено в `IL` и возможные побочные эффекты у пользователей таких либ.

Comment: Вообще рефлексии,  IL - это её часть - дозволено всё. Только нужно знать как. Достоинство/недостаток IL в том, что под IL-код будет сгенерирована ещё одна dll. А доступ можно получить везде, не прибегая к IL

Comment: Пожалуй... Используя IL можно 1)делать хорошо-оптимизированый IL код 2) можно делать "автогенерируемые" сборки. Т.е. что б не компилировать код через cs-ку, можно используя IL сделать сборку с нужными методами. (используется для генерации обмена в Entity).

Comment: @nick_n_a , ну т.е в IL отсутствует инкапсуляция, а модификаторы для языков высокого уровня, что бы компилятор из них не позволял нарушать инкапсуляцию?

Comment: P.S А нет ли чтива какого, желательно на русском по IL ?

Comment: Ну вроде бы декларативная инкапсуляция точно есть: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEzoMIFgAoAbyPXMwzADth0ANAbjIoAcAnMANwENgBTdDToBNZoQroOAewEBjATCG10ALXEBfIA==

Comment: @VladD, ну ею можно принебрегать? Просто, если нельзя, то я не понимаю, как сгенерированный лямбда сеттер для приватного поля будет эффективнее стандартной рефлексии.

Comment: @iluxa1810: А у меня почему-то не работает: «Необработанное исключение: System.FieldAccessException: Методу "Program.Main()" не удалось получить доступ к полю "C.Y". Program.Main()» при доступе к приватному полю.

Comment: @VladD, хм... Тогда я в недоумении почему кодогенерация быстрее рефлексии. Ок, в пабликом может оно и быстрее, так как сгенерированный код сразу знает о наличии того или иного свойства. Но как быть с приватными полями? Ведь кодогенерация еще и в сериализации учавствует. В Бинарном виде, можно и приватные поля восстанавливать.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Потому что рефлексия и правда вместо прямого обращения к полю использует доступ через `FieldInfo`. А вот в IL-коде прямой доступ, такой же, как и на C# в случае, когда тип известен заранее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможности IL несколько шире возможностей C#, например можно распаковывать объекты по ссылке:

```
ldarg_0
unbox [mscorlib]System.Int32
ldc.i4 42
stobj [mscorlib]System.Int32
ret
```

Вот к чему такое приводит:

```
object obj = -1;
Foo(obj);
Console.WriteLine(obj); // 42
```

Однако, большинство ограничений C# и IL - общие: язык C#, особенно в последних версиях, позволяет очень многое из того что позволяется средой выполнения. И да, просто так обращаться к приватным полям в IL - нельзя.

---

На самом деле, в приведенном вами примере обращение к приватному полю стало возможным не только из-за того что это IL, но еще и из-за того что использовался [динамический метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Динамические методы могут обходить проверки видимости если у создавшего их кода достаточно привилегий (и обход проверок был включён для этого метода параметром конструктора)

Comment: Хм... А как в IL-коде выглядит динамический метод? У него какой-то спец. атрибут для обхода валидации или динамический метод должен быть создан обязательно в рантайме, что бы читать приватные поля?

Comment: @iluxa1810 именно так - он должен быть создан в рантайме с использованием класса DynamicMethod. Это единственное отличие.

Answer (score 4):

В il-коде [можно](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=44349) помечать функции как экспортируемые, которые можно будет вызывать из нативного (не дотнетного) кода. Судя по всему, сам MS эту возможность вообще не афиширует. В компиляторы C# и VB.NET они эту фичу точно не добавили, про плюсы не в курсе.

Answer (score 3):

Используя IL можно выполнять CLR-команды https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions в любом порядке, каком захочется. Можно даже нарушать safe-концепцию и т п. не запрещено. Рефлексия сама по-себе позволяет получить доступ и к приватным и к другим членам класса. А IL - это язык команд. Можно создать как хорошо-оптимизированый IL-код, так и код который поломает приложение.

Но что важно, что IL-код не может существовать "сам по себе", он оформляется как сборка. Это свойство используется для генерации Entity, например. Код вида

```
 foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.Props) 
      do_something
```

На IL можно через цикл реализовать можно так (условно) https://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.prog.csharplessons/200703/21001224.html/

```
 ldarg.1
 getprop a
 do_something
 ldarg.1
 getprop b
 do_something
```

Но нужно понимать, что для даного il (который генерируете не вы, а ваш автомат)

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.Props) {
    il.Emit(OpCodes.ldarg1);
    //....
    }
```

нужно создать сборку, если используется динамический assembly - то будет создана временная сборка (темповый файл с dll).

О быстродействии, компиляция IL занимает время (если использовать динамическое формирование IL кода), если механизм будет использован 1 раз - ускорения не будет. Если у вас миллион вызовов по свойствам (такое часто в СУБД) - то лучше создать сборку. Потому что для доступа через привычную рефлексию (foreach, Properties, SetValue) используется в 10-20 раз больше IL-команд чем просто через IL (три команды ldarg,ldarg,setprop плюс минус). Есть либы, которое это делают автоматом.

Вообщем IL позволяет делать самомодифицирующийся(условно) код, или компилировать код неприбегая к "csc.exe".

Если цель - получить доступ к приватному свойству - то оно чаще всего доступно просто через рефлексию.

Comment: А можно немного подробнее (или ссылку, где почитать) о том, что приватные поля недоступны в системных библиотеках?