# Создание переменной определенного типа в зависимости от id

Tags: c#

Есть абстрактный тип `Data`, от него наследуются конкретные типы `DataA`, `DataB`, `DataC` и т.д. (по хорошему, в моей задаче `DataA`, `DataB`, ... - это структуры, а не классы, поэтому их не может объединять абстрактный тип, но для простоты пусть это будут классами). У каждого типа `Data` есть свой `id` [0, 255]. Необходимо реализовать метод, который будет возвращать `Data` в зависимости от `id`:

```
public Data CreateDataInstance(int id);
```

Если решать задачу в лоб, то получится что-то такое:

```
public Data CreateDataInstance(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 0:
            return new DataA();
        case 1:
            return new DataB();
        //...
        case 255:
            return new DataXXX();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Мне этот большой `switch` не очень нравится, потому что потом в случае изменения кода придется менять этот `switch/case`. Мне это все напоминает *фабричный метод*, но вот уже долго мучаюсь и никак не могу допереть, как его здесь применить, чтобы избавиться от switch/case.

В момент написания вопроса появилась идея создать все типы фабрик при запуске программы и запихать их в массив или список, и по `id` их доставать и создавать нужный `Data`. Но, может быть, есть более элегантный метод?

**UPD.** Решил вопрос с помощью фабрики. Теперь возник следующий вопрос: вот у меня есть список `List<Data>`. Как теперь, зная `Data.id`, совершить восходящее преобразование от общего `Data` к конкретному `DataX`? Неужели `switch/case` не избежать?

**UPD2.** Есть подозрение, что у меня не все в порядке с архитектурой приложения

Comment: А вам точно нужны именно разные структуры DataA..Z?

Comment: @Сергей не обязательно. Просто у меня из массива байт данные запоминаются в структуры через `Marshal.PtrToStructure` и я бы хотел работать именно с этими структурами, а так придется создавать классы помимо структур. Все структуры имеют различный набор полей. И этот набор полей зависит от `id`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Существует ли возможность создавать объект определенного типа, без использования класса Activator?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/860901/186999), возможно дубликат?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Способы создания объектов в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715920/186999)

Comment: *Как теперь, зная Data.id, совершить восходящее преобразование от общего Data к конкретному DataX?* — ??? Вы уверены, что это вам нужно? Вы это даже написать в принципе не сможете, все типы переменных **должны быть определены на этапе компиляции**

Comment: Если вы уже создали список данных, и вам нужно проделать над ними всеми какую-то операцию, почему бы не решить через полиморфизм?

Comment: Ну т.е. пусть id=1 это DataA, как вы это запишете даже со switch/case?

Comment: @АндрейNOP С помощью `switch` с 255 ветками - смогу. Есть вариант каждый тип `DataX` хранить в отдельных списках. Но это ж будет 255 списков... В общем, я пока в замешательстве

Comment: Ну ок, куда вы будете писать результат апкаста в каждой ветке? а) В одну и ту же переменную? Тогда она должна иметь общий тип Data и это не будет иметь смысла. б) В разные переменные? Тогда у вас в каждой ветке будут разные алгоритмы и эту задачу надо решать с помощью полиморфизма, а не свича

Comment: @AndreiKhotko а какая вообще в целом задача стоит, что ее так вот решать пришлось? Десериализация какая-нибудь?

Comment: @АндрейNOP упс, действительно. Сейчас мне просто нужно было вывести все `data` с `id == 128`. Про switch забудьте, я сглупил. А вот что дальше - пока мутно. Чуть позже объясню вам, что именно я хочу сделать. Если у вас есть желание помочь мне решить проблему, можем переместиться в чат, там бы я подробно пояснил, что именно мне нужно сделать. Это уже выходит за рамки вопроса.

Comment: @trollingchar есть бинарный файл. Он хранит в себе список "сообщений". Количество типов этих сообщений - 256. Нужно все эти сообщения "прочитать" в программе, чтобы потом можно было их отобразить в виде графиков (каждое сообщение содержит в себе N уникальных параметров (N параметров - это те самые поля у структур `DataX`), каждый из которых можно будет отобразить отдельной линией на графике). Как-то так.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko тогда может в чат перейдем? У меня есть как некоторые идеи так и вопросы

Comment: @trollingchar давайте перейдем в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96376/discuss-datax-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так (в предположении, что все наследники в одной сборке, и что наплевать на производительность):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    abstract class Data
    {
        public static Data CreateDataInstance(int id)
        {
            var derived = typeof(Data).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Data));
            var types = derived.Where(
                    t => (t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataIdAttribute)) as DataIdAttribute).ID == id
                );
            if (types.Count() == 0) throw new MissingMemberException("No such type with ID "+id.ToString());            

            Type type = types.First();
            return (Data)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }

    class DataIdAttribute : Attribute
    {
        int _id;

        public int ID { get { return _id; } }

        public DataIdAttribute(int id)
        {
            _id = id;
        }
    }

    [DataId(1)]
    class DataA : Data
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "DataA";
        }
    }

    [DataId(2)]
    class DataB : Data
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "DataB";
        }
    }
}
```

Если же производительность важна, но допустимы некоторые накладные расходы при первом обращении, можно предложить более громоздкое оптимизированное решение:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    abstract class Data
    {
        static Dictionary<int, Delegate> delegcache = new Dictionary<int, Delegate>();

        public static Data CreateDataInstance(int id)
        {
            Delegate deleg;
            if (delegcache.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                deleg = delegcache[id];
            }
            else
            {
                var derived = typeof(Data).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Data));
                var types = derived.Where(
                        t => (t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataIdAttribute)) as DataIdAttribute).ID == id
                    );
                if (types.Count() == 0) throw new MissingMemberException("No such type with ID " + id.ToString());

                Type type = types.First();
                NewExpression expr = Expression.New(type);
                LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr);
                deleg = lambda.Compile();
                delegcache[id] = deleg;
            }

            return (Data)deleg.DynamicInvoke();
        }
    }

    class DataIdAttribute : Attribute
    {
        int _id;

        public int ID { get { return _id; } }

        public DataIdAttribute(int id)
        {
            _id = id;
        }
    }

    [DataId(1)]
    class DataA : Data
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "DataA";
        }
    }

    [DataId(2)]
    class DataB : Data
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "DataB";
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так как-то

```
interface ICommonData
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
struct DataA : ICommonData
{
    string DataA1 { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

и т.д....затем

```
     private Dictionary<byte, Type> types;
     private List<ICommonData> data = new List<ICommonData>();

        types = new Dictionary<byte, Type>();
        types[1] = typeof(DataA);
        types[2] = typeof(DataB);
        types[3] = typeof(DataC);
        types[4] = typeof(DataD);
        types[5] = typeof(DataE);
```

и уже далее

```
        for (byte i = 0; i < byte.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            if (types.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                data.Add((ICommonData)Activator.CreateInstance(types[i]));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Про `Type` и не догадался, неплохо! Может быть, вы знаете, насколько по производительности такой подход отличается по производительности от того же фабричного метода? Больше всего меня интересует эта строка по производительности: `(ICommonData)Activator.CreateInstance(types[i]));`

Comment: Отличается в худшую сторону. Это же рефлексия...(ну все так говорят). А вообще нужно мерить и если это разовая акция, то я думаю не критично...Ежели надо тысячами создавать структуры постоянно, то будет заметно

Comment: Тогда не очень устроит, потому как нужно будет вызывать эту штуку около 10000-20000 раз

Comment: Это не много. Будет быстро работать

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, можно взять CustomActivator здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608238/218063

Comment: @СергейСинельников взял на вооружение. Я обновил вопрос, взгляните, пожалуйста

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вот через expression будет работать побыстрее.

Comment: @СергейСинельников и да, я немного соврал: количество будет не `20 000`, а около `600 000`